# Android, Gradle, Espresso: When add new dependency get error: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError'

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

My Android Espresso test:

```
package com.example.testproject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsNot.not;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainActivityTest {
    private static String TAG;
    private Context context;

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity_> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity_.class);

    @Before
    public void init() {
        TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
        context = mActivityRule.getActivity();
    }

    @Test
    public void checkClick() {
        onView(withId(R.id.myButton)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.myTextView)).check(matches(withText(R.string.you_click)));
    }
}
```

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.testproject"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        // Enabling Multidex support for 'androidTest' builds because of large dependencies
        // need for androidTest
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'

        exclude 'mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker'
    }
}

def AAVersion = '4.3.0'

dependencies {

    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    compile 'us.feras.mdv:markdownview:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.mukeshsolanki:MarkdownView-Android:1.0.3'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.4'

    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava'
        exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
    }
}
```

I run Espresso test by gradle from command line:

```
gradlew connectedAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.example.testproject.MainActivityTest#checkClick
```

and Espresso test success run and execute. OK!

Now I want to use lib WireMock to test http request/response.
So I change my dependencies in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {

    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    compile 'us.feras.mdv:markdownview:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.mukeshsolanki:MarkdownView-Android:1.0.3'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.4'

    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava'
        exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
    }

    //WireMock
    androidTestCompile("com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:2.5.0") {
        //Using Android Version Instead
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'

        //Version conflict with our app's slf4j version
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-api'

        //Was getting a classpath conflict for org.objectweb.asm.AnnotationVisitor which is a part of 'net.minidev:asm'
        exclude group: 'org.ow2.asm', module: 'asm'

        //Was getting this warning, so decided to ignore this version included by WireMock.
        //Warning:Dependency org.json:json:20090211 is ignored as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
        //In case of problem, please repackage with jarjar to change the class packages
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    androidTestCompile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
    androidTestCompile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
}
```

And now when I run same Espresso test I get error:

```
    gradlew connectedAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.example.testproject.MainActivityTest#checkClick --debug --stacktrace

...
:app:assembleDebugAndroidTest UP-TO-DATE
:app:connectedDebugAndroidTest
Starting 0 tests on Galaxy Nexus - 4.3
Tests on Galaxy Nexus - 4.3 failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError'

com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > No tests found.[Galaxy Nexus - 4.3] FAILED 
No tests found. This usually means that your test classes are not in the form that your test runner expects (e.g. don't inherit from TestCase or lack @Test annotations).
:app:connectedDebugAndroidTest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:connectedDebugAndroidTest'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///D:/dev/mobile/TestProject/app/build/reports/androidTests/connected/index.html

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:connectedDebugAndroidTest'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:196)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///D:/dev/mobile/TestProject/app/build/reports/androidTests/connected/index.html
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DeviceProviderInstrumentTestTask.runTests(DeviceProviderInstrumentTestTask.java:160)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:141)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:632)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:615)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
    ... 70 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 18.614 secs
```

I found solutions of problem:

If you use Android 5.0- (e.g. Android 4.3) then you **MUST** use Wiremock version **2.0.8-beta**

```
androidTestCompile 'com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:2.0.8-beta'
```

If you use Android 5.0+ you can you use any Wiremock version (e.g. 2.5.0)

```
androidTestCompile 'com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:2.6.0'
```

P.S. Maybe this is a Multidex issues.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Were you able to run tests using gradlew command? I read on android documentation that we can run our tests through command-line either using gradlew or using adb shell pm command. I tried using adb shell pm command to run tests but the problem with it is that it doesn't create test reports. For test-reports, I am trying to run tests through gradlew but it keeps giving NoClassDef error. Any help will be appreaciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Now I'm using another library - Retrofit 2. In this library I can write transport tests from out-of-box.